# Moving variable text to the right side

Tags: html, css, element

I made a month/season counter which after a button is pressed changes the name of a var to a specific month and season (the season is underneath) the whole thing is on the right side of the screen with float right and some position adjustments with margin-right and so when it comes to "summer" the whole thing moves a bit to the left instead on the right as it did previously without adding "float: right" and "margin-right". I don´t really know how to fix it and I don´t think that somehow changing the position for each specific season/month is the right answer.
I am thankful for any help.

```js
var numbermonth = 3;
        var month = "March";
        var season = "Spring";

        setInterval(function () {
          document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
            document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;
            document.getElementById("numbermonth");
        }, 50);

function cekani() {
            numbermonth += 1;


            if (numbermonth == 1) {
                month = "January";
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
            }


            if (numbermonth == 2) {
                month = "February";
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


            }

            if (numbermonth == 3) {
                month = "March";
                season = "Spring";
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
                document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;


            }

            if (numbermonth == 4) {
                month = "April";
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


            }

            if (numbermonth == 5) {
                month = "May";
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
                document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;

            }

            if (numbermonth == 6) {
                month = "June";
                season = "Summer"
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


            }

            if (numbermonth == 7) {
                month = "July";
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
                document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;


            }

            if (numbermonth == 8) {
                month = "August";
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


            }

            if (numbermonth == 9) {
                month = "September";
                season = "Autumn"
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
                document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;


            }

            if (numbermonth == 10) {
                month = "October";
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


            }

            if (numbermonth == 11) {
                month = "November";
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


            }

            if (numbermonth == 12) {
                month = "December";
                season = "Winter"
                document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
                document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;
                numbermonth = 0;

            }

            if (season == "Spring") {
                food = food + farmers * 2;
                food = food - (lide + farmers)
                document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = food;

            }

            if (season == "Summer") {
                food = food + farmers * 3;
                food = food - (lide + farmers)
                document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = food;
            }

            if (season == "Autumn") {
                food = food + farmers * 1.25;
                food = food - (lide + farmers)
                document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = food;
            }

            if (season == "Winter") {
                food = food + farmers * 0.50;
                food = food - (lide + farmers)
                document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = food;
            }



        }

    </script>
```

```css
#sezonaMesic {
            float: right;
            margin-top: -2.15%;
            margin-right: 2.5%;
        }
        
        #casTabulka {
            float: right;
            margin-top: -3.01%;
            margin-right: 6%;
        }
```

```html
<table id="sezonaMesic">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="linky" style="font-size: 320%">
                        <b>
                            <img src="nextmonth.png" alt="button" style="width: 200px; height: 90px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="cekani()">
                        </b>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<table id="casTabulka">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="linky" style="font-size: 300%">
                        <b>
                            Month = <element id="month"></element><br> Season = <element id="season"></element>
                        </b>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

This should be a working snippet. IDK if it looks good, most likely not but I want that text to expand on the right side

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a **[Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)**.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I think this snippet should work

Comment: Your problem is that the word "summer" is longer than the word for any other season, so it pushes over to the left in order to fit that word in. Try adding a border around the #season element to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens because the container doesn't have a specified size, so it adjusts to the size of its content. Then, when the name of the month/season changes, it makes the container larger/smaller, and that causes the "jumps" to left and right respectively.

One quick solution would be to add a size to the container of the text that will change (in this case it would be for `#casTabulka .linky`). But adding the width will not be enough because if the words inside are too long, they will cause a line break and jump into multiple lines. To prevent this, you could use `white-space: nowrap` to make the whole content of the container as a single word (thus not breaking into multiple lines). Something like this:

```
#casTabulka .linky {
  width: 400px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You can see how after adding those changes there is no jump anymore (you may need to adjust the size so it doesn't overlap the button):

```js
var numbermonth = 3;
var month = "March";
var season = "Spring";

setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
  document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;
  document.getElementById("numbermonth");
}, 50);

function cekani() {
  numbermonth += 1;


  if (numbermonth == 1) {
    month = "January";
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
  }


  if (numbermonth == 2) {
    month = "February";
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


  }

  if (numbermonth == 3) {
    month = "March";
    season = "Spring";
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
    document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;


  }

  if (numbermonth == 4) {
    month = "April";
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


  }

  if (numbermonth == 5) {
    month = "May";
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
    document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;

  }

  if (numbermonth == 6) {
    month = "June";
    season = "Summer"
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


  }

  if (numbermonth == 7) {
    month = "July";
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
    document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;


  }

  if (numbermonth == 8) {
    month = "August";
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


  }

  if (numbermonth == 9) {
    month = "September";
    season = "Autumn"
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
    document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;


  }

  if (numbermonth == 10) {
    month = "October";
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


  }

  if (numbermonth == 11) {
    month = "November";
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;


  }

  if (numbermonth == 12) {
    month = "December";
    season = "Winter"
    document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month;
    document.getElementById("season").innerHTML = season;
    numbermonth = 0;

  }

  if (season == "Spring") {
    food = food + farmers * 2;
    food = food - (lide + farmers)
    document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = food;

  }

  if (season == "Summer") {
    food = food + farmers * 3;
    food = food - (lide + farmers)
    document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = food;
  }

  if (season == "Autumn") {
    food = food + farmers * 1.25;
    food = food - (lide + farmers)
    document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = food;
  }

  if (season == "Winter") {
    food = food + farmers * 0.50;
    food = food - (lide + farmers)
    document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = food;
  }



}
```

```css
#sezonaMesic {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -2.15%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}

#casTabulka {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -3.01%;
  margin-right: 6%;
}

#casTabulka .linky {
  width: 400px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table id="sezonaMesic">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="linky" style="font-size: 320%">
        <b>
                            <img src="nextmonth.png" alt="button" style="width: 200px; height: 90px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="cekani()">
                        </b>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="casTabulka">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="linky" style="font-size: 300%">
        <b>
                            Month = <element id="month"></element><br> Season = <element id="season"></element>
                        </b>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really did help a lot!